# Visual Studio C++ trigger a breakpoint at the end of main function

Tags: c++, breakpoints

Me and my group is making a game for our project and I keep running into this error, after some testing, it looks like it happens at the end of the main function. I have no idea how this happen as most of the code is from our teacher, we need to fix the intentional bugs placed by him and add additional functionalities.
This is the code:

```
#include <winuser.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_CAR 5
#define MAX_CAR_LENGTH 40
#define MAX_SPEED 3

POINT** X;
POINT Y;
int cnt = 0;
int MOVING;
int SPEED;
int HEIGHT_CONSOLE = 29, WIDTH_CONSOLE = 119;
bool STATE;

void FixConsoleWindow() {
    HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE);
    style = style & ~(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX) & ~(WS_THICKFRAME);
    SetWindowLongPtr(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, style);
}

void GotoXY(int x, int y) {
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void ResetData() {
    MOVING = 'D';
    SPEED = 1;
    Y = { 18,  19 };
    if (X == NULL) {
        X = new POINT * [MAX_CAR];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i++) {
            X[i] = new POINT[MAX_CAR_LENGTH];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i++) {
            int temp = rand() % (WIDTH_CONSOLE - MAX_CAR_LENGTH) + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_CAR_LENGTH; j++) {
                X[i][j].x = temp + j;
                X[i][j].y = 2 + 5 * i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void DrawBoard(int x, int y, int width, int height, int curPosX = 0, int curPosY = 0) {
    GotoXY(x, y);
    for (int i = 1; i < width; i++) {
        cout << 'X';
    }
    cout << 'X';
    GotoXY(x, height + y);
    for (int i = 1; i < width; i++) {
        cout << 'X';
    }
    cout << 'X';
    for (int i = y + 1; i < height + y; i++) {
        GotoXY(x, i);
        cout << 'X';
        GotoXY(x + width, i);
        cout << 'X';
    }
    GotoXY(curPosX, curPosY);
}

void StartGame() {
    system("cls");
    ResetData();
    DrawBoard(0, 0, WIDTH_CONSOLE, HEIGHT_CONSOLE);
    STATE = true;
}

void GabageCollect() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i++) {
        delete[] X[i];
    }
    delete[] X;
}

void ExitGame(HANDLE t) {
    GabageCollect();
    system("cls");
    TerminateThread(t, 0);
}

void PauseGame(HANDLE t) {
    SuspendThread(t);
}

void ProcessDeath() {
    STATE = false;
    GotoXY(0, HEIGHT_CONSOLE + 2);
    cout << "Dead, type y to continue or any key to exit";
}

void ProcessFinish(POINT& p) {
    SPEED == MAX_SPEED ? SPEED = 1 : SPEED++;
    p = { 18,19 };
    MOVING = 'D';
}

void DrawCars() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_CAR_LENGTH; j++) {
            GotoXY(X[i][j].x, X[i][j].y);
            std::cout << '.';
        }
    }
}

void DrawPlayer(const POINT& p, char s) {
    GotoXY(p.x, p.y);
    cout << s;
}

bool IsImpact(const POINT& p) //d=Y.y     p = Y
{
    if (p.y == 1 || p.y == 19) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_CAR_LENGTH; j++)
        {
            if (p.x == X[i][j].x && p.y == X[i][j].y) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void MoveCars(int x1, int y1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_CAR; i += 2)
    {
        cnt = 0;
        do
        {
            cnt++;
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1; j++)
            {
                X[i][j] = X[i][j + 1];
            }
            X[i][MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1].x + 1 == WIDTH_CONSOLE + x1 ? X[i][MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1].x = 1 : X[i][MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1].x++;
        } while (cnt < SPEED);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i += 2)
    {
        cnt = 0;
        do
        {
            cnt++;
            for (int j = MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1; j > 0; j--)
            {
                X[i][j] = X[i][j - 1];
            }
            X[i][0].x - 1 == 0 + x1 ? X[i][0].x = WIDTH_CONSOLE + x1 - 1 : X[i][0].x--;
        } while (cnt < SPEED);
    }
}


void EraseCars()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CAR; i += 2)
    {
        cnt = 0;
        do
        {
            GotoXY(X[i][MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1 - cnt].x, X[i][MAX_CAR_LENGTH - 1 - cnt].y);
            cout << " ";
            cnt++;
        } while (cnt < SPEED);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_CAR; i += 2)
    {
        cnt = 0;
        do
        {
            GotoXY(X[i][0 + cnt].x, X[i][0 + cnt].y);
            cout << " ";
            cnt++;
        } while (cnt < SPEED);
    }
}


void MoveRight()
{
    if (Y.x < WIDTH_CONSOLE - 1)
    {
        DrawPlayer(Y, ' ');
        Y.x++;
        DrawPlayer(Y, 'Y');
    }
}

void MoveLeft()
{
    if (Y.x > 1)
    {
        DrawPlayer(Y, ' ');
        Y.x--;
        DrawPlayer(Y, 'Y');
    }
}

void MoveDown()
{
    if (Y.y < HEIGHT_CONSOLE - 1)
    {
        DrawPlayer(Y, ' ');
        Y.y++;
        DrawPlayer(Y, 'Y');
    }
}

void MoveUp()
{
    if (Y.y > 1)
    {
        DrawPlayer(Y, ' ');
        Y.y--;
        DrawPlayer(Y, 'Y');
    }
}

void SubThread()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (STATE)
        {
            switch (MOVING)
            {
            case 'A':
                MoveLeft();
                break;
            case 'D':
                MoveRight();
                break;
            case'W':
                MoveUp();
                break;
            case'S':
                MoveDown();
                break;
            }
            MOVING = ' ';
            EraseCars();
            MoveCars(0, 0);
            DrawCars();
            if (IsImpact(Y))
            {
                ProcessDeath();
            }
            if (Y.y == 1)
            {
                ProcessFinish(Y);
                Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
}
void main()
{
    int temp;
    FixConsoleWindow();
    srand(time(NULL));
    StartGame();
    thread t1(SubThread);
    while (1)
    {
        temp = toupper(_getch());
        if (STATE == 1)
        {
            EraseCars();
            if (temp == 27)
            {
                ExitGame(t1.native_handle());
                break;
            }
            else if (temp == 'P')
            {
                PauseGame(t1.native_handle());
                temp = toupper(_getch());
                if (temp == 'B')
                    ResumeThread((HANDLE)t1.native_handle());
            }
            else
            {
                if (temp == 'D' || temp == 'A' || temp == 'W' || temp == 'S')
                {
                    MOVING = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp == 'Y') StartGame();
            else
            {
                ExitGame(t1.native_handle());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the image of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1wXe.jpg
Basically, this is a crossing road game, every time you go to the top, it saves the location and you cannot go that location again (still working on this), game finish when you run into the cars (lines of dots as of the moment). Thanks in advance

Comment: "this error" -- what error?

Comment: Oh right, i forgot to add the error picture, give me a minute

Comment: Ok, i just added the image link of the error

Answer (score 0):

You created a [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) object here:

```
thread t1(SubThread);
```

but you didn't call [`join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) nor [`detach()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) for that.

This causes that `std::terminate()` is called (the program aborts) when the object is [destructed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread).

Call `t1.join()` if you want to wait until the thread ends or `t1.detach()` if you want to let the thread run freely before returning from the `main()` function.

Another option is using [`CreateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) directly instead of `std::thread` to create threads. This may be better because you are using `t1.native_handle()` for operations on the thread.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I add the detach function? I'm new to this whole thread subject